# Empty user's cart without logging them out, after 72 hours in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to programmatically empty a user's cart after 72 hours of non-activity. Is there a way to find out when a cart was last updated?

I tried to pull a dump of the cart variable, but I could not find a timestamp anywhere indicating the last time a user added something in there.

**Not wanting to use a plugin for this please!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code below will set a timestamp as custom cart item data each time a product is added to cart:

```
// Set current date time as custom item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data_timestamp', 10, 3 );
function add_cart_item_data_timestamp( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    // Set the shop time zone (List of Supported Timezones: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Paris' );

    $cart_item_data['timestamp'] = strtotime( date('Y-m-d h:i:s') );

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Then the following hooked function will empty cart, when last added item has been added after 72 hours:

```
// Empty cart after 3 days
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'empty_cart_after_3_days' );
function empty_cart_after_3_days(){
    if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return; // Exit

    // Set the shop time zone (List of Supported Timezones: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Paris' );

    // Set the threshold time in seconds (3 days in seconds)
    $threshold_time  = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60;
    $threshold_time  = 1 * 60 * 60;

    $cart_items      = WC()->cart->get_cart(); // get cart items
    $cart_items_keys = array_keys($cart_items); // get cart items keys array
    $last_item       = end($cart_items); // Last cart item
    $last_item_key   = end($cart_items_keys); // Last cart item key
    $now_timestamp   = strtotime( date('Y-m-d h:i:s') ); // Now date time

    if( isset($last_item['timestamp']) && ( $now_timestamp - $last_item['timestamp'] ) >= $threshold_time ) {
        WC()->cart->empty_cart(); // Empty cart
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was waiting 12 hours to test if it worked. Thank you so so much for this. Have a great day!

Comment: The 10, 3 means: no priority (1 a lot, 10 not much) and the number of arguments of the function (3) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/